# Unable To Change File Name Before Upload

Tags: php

I have a PHP file like following and I tried to change the file name and give it a random name and then save it on the server by using

```
 $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
      $newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . $newfilename);
```

in following code

Html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

and  `upload.php` PHP

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . $newfilename);
}
?>
```

but this is creating a file like `test.png123472.png` a combination of original file name `test.png` and `123472.png` !
Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in following line

```html
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file . $newfilename);
```

Instead above line use following line

```html
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir. $newfilename);
```

And Remove following line from your code:

```html
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
 $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0]);
  $newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp);
```

Comment: Thanks Manadh, but this also generating wrong name! this time name look like `test.png76502.m`